# Changing SqlDataSource SelectCommand and SelectParameter with a button

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString9.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([oStatus] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="CheckedOut" Name="oStatus" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Above is the code for the SqlDataSource. What I am trying to do is to add a button which will help me add an additional WHERE condition into SelectCommand and add the SelectParameters for the added condition.

Button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" text="filter record" ID="filterbutton" OnClick="filterbutton_Click"/>
```

What I want the SelectCommand to look like when button is clicked

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([oStatus] = ?) AND ([oDelivery_Status] = ?)">
```

Question is it is possible to add more than 1 SelectParameters? And is it possible to do so with a button OnClick method? If not, are there any other solutions/methods? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both Parameters which you want in your `SelectCommand` like this:

```
protected void filterbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        string stroStatus = "";
        string stroDelivery_Status = "";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["oStatus"].DefaultValue = stroStatus;
        Parameter pm = SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["oDelivery_Status"];


        if (!SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Contains(pm))
        {
           SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("oDelivery_Status",   
           stroDelivery_Status);
        }
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([oStatus] = @oStatus) AND ([oDelivery_Status] = @oDelivery_Status)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! However, after I try to string stroDelivery_Status to a DropDownList text, the button only works after the first click, and not anymore after. Here are the codes for the string

    `string stroDelivery_Status = DropDownList2.Text;` 

How do I make it such that the button will work after the first use?

Comment: @user7381027 did you put a debugger. button does not get fired second time ?

Comment: Do you think the problem lies with this line of code? `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("oDelivery_Status", stroDelivery_Status);`  ? Since after the second click the previous parameter added (from first click) is not removed, hence I will have 3 parameters

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the updated code but same thing happened again, button only works for the first click and not the subsequent ones.

Comment: @user7381027 what happens in second click did you set break point to check whats actually not happening in your case.